# start tomcat with specific java parameters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications

I am starting Tomcat using the startup.bat in the TOMCAT_HOME\bin directory.
I need to enable all the java's debugging traces.
In my web app (Note: Actually it is an axis2 web service) I did:
`System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");`
But it did not work.
Nothing printed to Tomcat console.
I tried to put this property as parameter in Tomcat on start-up so I edited the catalina.bat as follows:
Before:

```
if not "%LOGGING_MANAGER%" == "" goto noJuliManager
set LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
:noJuliManager
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%
```

After:

```
if not "%LOGGING_MANAGER%" == "" goto noJuliManager
set LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
:noJuliManager
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%
set JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.debug=all %JAVA_OPTS%
```

I am not sure if this is the write place to put it in catalina.bat, but it seemed reasonable to me.
No success as well.
So how can I start tomcat with a -Djava option?
Specifically how can I enable

`System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");`
so that I can do the debugging in my web app?

Thank you.

Comment: You are in the right direction. With the -D think works for me all the time. :(

Comment: @Pablo:Any idea what I am doing wrong and no debug info is printed to console?

Comment: @user384706: Do you happen to have JMX installed? To make sure your -D is being read? Try running catalina manually. In unix, you would see the -D on the invocation with `ps aux | grep java`.

Comment: @Pablo:I am running in windows.I tried "catalina start" but no success either.Do not know the equivalent of `ps aux | grep java` for windows

Answer (score 5):

The "official" way to set extra parameters to Tomcat is via creating `bin/catalina.sh` in Unix or `bin\catalina.bat` in Windows. In your (Windows) case, the file should look like as follows:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Djavax.net.debug=all
```

Comment: Tried it but no success.But may be I am wrong here.I see in the java code the following: `if (debug != null) {debug.println("---checking " + msg + "..."); etc` is this not supposed to go to console? Also no extra debugging traces are shown in the Tomcat console even with this option

Comment: Try launch Tomcat by calling "catalina.bat run" so the output goes to your stdout (and watch it), maybe your logging configuration is misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

A hackish solution is to look for all the set JAVA_OPTS in catalina.bat AND startup.bat, and add something in there.

You should find one or more set JAVA_OPTS=......., and you can add something in there.
This is what I do whenever I need to add extra options, and I do not have time to see why
@mindas 's solution doesn't work.